# Perl bindings for using Selenium Server 3.0.1

Tags: perl, selenium

It seems that the perl module WWWW::Selenium does not work properly with seleniumserver standalone 3.0.1 Does anyone know if there is a later version than 1.36

It seems that Selenium recomends this perl binding:
https://www.github.com/gempesaw/Selenium-Remote-Driver. Which I have problems downloading. Does anyone know if any repository provides this module for windows (Active State Perl) free of charge? ActiveState does provide it, but then I would need to pay for a subscription. Are there any alternatives?
I have checked  bribes.org and latrouchelle neither of which seem to provide it.

I very much applogize if my question is lacking in any way, this is the first one I have written in this forum.

Answer (score 2):

> WWW::Selenium...Does anyone know if there is a later version than 1.36

No, the latest version is 1.36

> Selenium recommends [this](https://www.github.com/gempesaw/Selenium-Remote-Driver) perl binding

Yes you should be using [Selenium::Remote::Driver](https://metacpan.org/pod/Selenium::Remote::Driver).

> Does anyone know if any repository provides this module for windows (Active State Perl) free of charge?

Install the latest version of ActivePerl Community Edition (which is **Perl 5.24.0**). ActiveState does not provide free support for older versions of Perl. Therefore if you use the latest community edition then you'll be fine.

---

You can see at http://www.activestate.com/activeperl/downloads that for Perl version 5.20 and earlier you'll have to purchase Business Edition.

[image]

---

> I have checked bribes.org and latrouchelle neither of which seem to
>   provide it.

You can always use CPAN to install the module.

```
$ cpan Selenium::Remote::Driver
```

or

```
$ perl -MCPAN -eshell
> install Selenium::Remote::Driver
```

You can also consider using [**Strawberry Perl**: The Perl for MS Windows, free of charge!](http://strawberryperl.com/)